# Keyboard similar to laptop keyboards for a desktop

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics

I want to use a keyboard that requires minimal effort pushing down with minimal (if any at all) space between keys. I like the new Apple keyboards, but I want something closer to the feel of a laptop keyboard with flat buttons (the keys on the Apple keyboards are still raised up a bit). Are there any that fit this description? I *want* something touch-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a [laptop keyboard](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?cid=7341298921788466652#)?

Comment: Does that have a USB connection, then?

Comment: @Nathaniel: It does indeed.

Answer (score 3):

**update:** Lenovo recently updated the design of the legendary Thinkpad (external) keyboard based on user feedback:

> The Ultimate Compact Keyboard! The
>   ThinkPad USB Keyboard features an
>   elegant, ultra slim design with the
>   same low profile keys found on the
>   legendary ThinkPad keyboard. This
>   one-of-a-kind keyboard lets you save
>   valuable desk space and is the perfect
>   complement to your ThinkPad in the
>   office or at home.

[Lenovo online store](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=38&Code=55Y9003&current-category-id=E9ADAEB6787146E29B78400A33E7FE8A).

[The Keyboard You Helped Design](http://lenovoblogs.com/designmatters/?p=2364): Some history about the design of this external laptop keyboard.

[image]

---

Lenovo released exactly what you are looking for last year:

[image]

src: [geek.com](http://www.geek.com/articles/gadgets/lenovo-releases-thinkpad-keyboard-without-the-thinkpad-2009097/)

Comment: I own one of these. In my opinion it needs some extra side padding (macbook-style) so the hands can rest better.